# Solve $ \omega^2 \cdot w(x) + w''(x) + (n-1) / x \cdot w'(x) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I want to find all spherical standing waves in $\mathbb{R}^3$, i.e. all solutions of homogeneous wave equation in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of the form $u(x,t) = w(|x|) \sin(\omega t + \phi)$.

I noted that, if such $u(x,t)$ solves the wave equation, we must have:

\begin{equation}
u_{tt} - \Delta u = 0 \\
-\omega^2 w(|x|) \sin(\omega t + \phi) - (w''(|x|) + 2 w'(|x|) / |x|) \sin(\omega t + \phi) = 0
\end{equation}
So, in particular, any such $w$ must solve this ODE for $x > 0$:
\begin{equation}
\omega^2 w(x) + \frac{2w'(x)}{x} + w''(x) = 0
\end{equation}
However, I don't know how to solve this ODE - can anyone help me with that? Or are there other ways to find all spherical standing waves in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: For $n>2$ the DE in the title  looks like a Bessel differential equation

Answer (score 2):

$$\omega^2 w(x) + \frac{2w'(x)}{x} + w''(x) = 0$$
Substitute $u=\omega x$:
$$ w(u) + \frac{2w'(u)}{u} + w''(u) = 0$$
$$ uw(u) +{2w'(u)} + uw''(u) = 0$$
$$ uw(u) +( uw(u))'' = 0$$
This should be integrable since it's  a second order linear differential equation with constant coefficients.
$$y''(u)+y(u)=0$$
$$y(u)=c_1 \cos u +c_2 \sin u$$
where $y=uw(u)$.
$$w(x)=\dfrac 1 {\omega x}\left(c_1 \cos (\omega x) +c_2 \sin (\omega x)\right)$$